# Delete Metric in DataDog

Tags: metrics, datadog

I need to request a DataDog metric but in the metric is wrong data stored. Is there a possibility to remove data from a DataDog metric? I didn´t find any in the official documentation. Removing the whole metric would also be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metrics are recorded over time. Each value belongs to a specific point in time. Old values cannot be deleted or overwritten. There might be a better way of achieving what you're trying to do, but to give specific advice more detail on what you're trying to measure and how you're currently doing it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Going down the path of deleting the metric, you can stop sending log metrics by deleting them here:
https://app.datadoghq.com/logs/pipelines/generate-metrics

It will continue to be available in Metrics Summary / Explorer for 15 months, but this will stop sending them.

From there, you can re-create.